# Back EMF sensorless BLDC control

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, back-emf

I am trying to detect the zero crossing point of back emf in a bldc motor in order to control it sensorless. Do you have any idea what detection circuit should I use. I am thinking about a network resistor and 3 comparators on each phases. Thank you !

Comment: Impossible to answer if you don’t have the motor’s topology: delta or Y?

Comment: Of course is Y topology